# Script bug in Matlab about solving two variation

Tags: matlab

I m a new learner for matlab. And I recently try to figure out a programing about a course. But it cannot work...The matlab always warning me "Explicit solution could not be found". I have tried to find the bug for a long time, but failed. I think maybe there are some problems with the function "solve", but not sure about it. Hope you samrt guys could help me. Thx very much. Here is the script:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
%% definition
%% Initializtion
format shortg;
vpa(3);
M = 102509.83;
xg = 160.281;
L = 330.45;
syms a; syms b;
%% Trapezia 1
c = input('input the value of c:')
s_t1r = 0.3*L*a;
s_t1t = 0.3*L*(c-a)/2;
s_t1 = s_t1r+s_t1t;
x_t1 = (0.3*L*a*0.15*L+0.3*L*(c-a)/2*0.2*L)/s_t1;
%% Rectangle
s_r2 = 0.4*L*c;
x_r2 = 0.5*L;
%% Trapezia 2
s_t3r = 0.3*L*b;
s_t3t = 0.3*L*(c-b)/2;
s_t3 = s_t3r+s_t3t;
x_t3 = (s_t3r*0.15*L+s_t3t*0.2*L)/s_t3;
%% Equatation
eq1 = s_t1+s_r2+s_t3-M;
eq2 = s_t1*x_t1+s_r2*x_r2+s_t3*x_t3)/M-xg;
[a,b] = solve(eq1,eq2,'a','b')
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in `eq2`. Please make sure to copy **the exact code** with which you have a problem. Also, `vpa(3);` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thx....I m new comer to this community, I will be more and more experienced. :)

Comment: That's all right, and welcome:) Please use the "[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33356647/edit)" link below your question to edit it, and make sure your code is *exactly* the one you have a problem with.